# Where can I find .NET sources to download?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Where can I download source code for the .NET Framework? I mean sources of libraries. I need the source for reflection methods like `invoke` and other.

Comment: if your purpose is learning, than check mono source. check mono-project.com for detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by others you can use reflector and ILDASM to get the source of the framework code, however you should first visit http://referencesource.microsoft.com and [download the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/DotNetReferenceSource.zip) that MS has released.

I've done this with all the frameworks since 3.5

Comment: I don't think netmassdownloader is needed anymore. You can download the whole source in one file from the MS website.

Comment: @floele - please feel free update the answer with the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

You can [set up symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code) in Visual Studio to automatically be able to step in the framework code, or use [.NET Mass Downloader](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128084517/http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com:80/documentation) to download all the source files in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RedGates .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) with it comes a perfectly good dissassambler which can produce code for you, it even creates the files for you.