# Which download for .net source

Tags: .net

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942187/net-sources-to-download), looking here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx you see this list currently:

- Product Name Version View Download
- .NET 8.0
- dotnetfx1434_VistaWin2k8sp1 50727.1434
- FXUpdate3074 50727.3074
- ASP.NET_MVC 1.0
- WCF 3.5SP1
- WF 3.5SP1
- Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2 50727.4016
- Dotnetfx_Win7_3.5.1 3.5.1
- ASP.NET_MVC 2.0
- .Net 4
- .NET_3.5_sp1_redist 50727.3053
- ASP.NET_MVC 3
- Netfx_3.5.1_Win7SP1 3.5.1
- NET 4.5
- Net 4.5Update1

I'm not sure what ones I need to download. I have VS2010 and VS2012. `Net 4.5Update1`
 sounds good for VS2012, but after download the read me says "Seamless Integration with Visual Studio 2008/2010", but I assume that's just out of date readme.

What is `.NET 8.0`? and why are there so many different `3.5` versions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to an out of date webpage, so is of no use.

Comment: Does anyone have working links to download any of the old .NET sources? I need specifically the 2.0 and 3.5 versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get to see all the service packs, security updates and specific versions that come preinstalled with Windows.  Which is in general a problem with the Reference Source, they are always behind and source stepping tends to not work because of a version mismatch with the actual version of .NET you have on your machine.  I only ever got it to work once and that didn't last long.

.NET 8.0 is mislabeled with the VS version, version 8 was VS2005 and supported .NET version 2.0

Low expectations are recommended, the source is most useful for reading and searching.  A completely different approach is a decompiler that recovers the source code from the actual .NET assemblies at debug time.  Reflector has that feature, not otherwise an endorsement.

Comment: Thanks, I usually use Telerik JustDecompile. I actually saw in another question that resharper had mis-decompiled something, and that's something I have experienced too with Telerik.

Comment: Yes, every decompiler gets it wrong one way or another.  The Reference Source is both accurate and has comments, hard to beat.  A bug in a post-processing tool they use on the original source to remove programmer names and causes the source to be repeated twice and otherwise mangled in a few spots is a blemish.